# Qt getting a QWidget to reflect light

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt 4.6 to create a grid of golden plaques. I have done so using QLabel as my widget and setting its parent to QPixmap which contains a .jpg image of a plaque. The widgets then scroll up the screen out of sight. However, now I would like the plaques to shine as they move. I thought that QGraphicsEffect would have a function that would do that - much like its dropShadowEffect where the shadow changes position with regard to the light source. In a similar way, I am searching for a way that the shininess of each plaque would reflect from a light source as the widgets move.

So, for example, here is an example of a trophy glinting gold [Gold Trophy](http://www.123gifs.eu/gold/gif-pokal-0019.gif.html) or[2nd Gold Trophy](http://www.123gifs.eu/gold/page-8/) (look at the trophy that says 2nd on it). I would like to be able to add the same feature to my plaques. Any help would be greatly appreaciated

Comment: Can you draw a sample image of what would you expect to achive?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a reflection really, which itself would be pretty complex to achieve.

It is a clumsy fakery, basically you have an animated linear gradient going from transparent to white to transparent, which is masked by the alpha of the object it is supposed to be applied to as it moves across it.

If you are looking for a way to do that in Qt, it is most definitely not `QtWdigets`, it will be very inefficient. The right tool for this is QML - this is how easy it is:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: main
    width: 200
    height: 200
    visible: true
    color: "black"

    Grid {
        x: 15
        y: 15
        id: grid
        rows: 3
        columns: 3
        spacing: 10

        Repeater {
            model: 9
            Rectangle {
                radius: 10
                width: 50
                height: 50
                color: "gold"
                border.color: "orange"
                border.width: 5
            }
        }
    }

    LinearGradient {
        id: effect
        anchors.fill: grid
        source: grid
        rotation: -90
        property real p : pos.mouseX / pos.width
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: effect.p - 0.05; color: "#00FFFFFF"}
            GradientStop { position: effect.p; color: "#FFFFFFFF"}
            GradientStop { position: effect.p + 0.05; color: "#00FFFFFF"}
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: pos
        anchors.fill: grid
        hoverEnabled: true
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

The light in this example will move with the mouse position.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem is - I only have Qt 4.6. I am not able to implement qml in it. Do you have any suggestions for making lighting work on a qwidget still. I know its difficult - but even a broad outline  might work. From what you have written, it seems to have something to do with the Linear Gradient?

Comment: "I only have Qt 4.6" - well, why don't you get a newer version, after all... you know, it's free. The "broad outline" is the second paragraph from the answer, it is also used for the QML example, it is just that QML does most of the work for you, with QtWidgets you will have to draw everything manually.